# Win+1,2,3, etc. equivalent for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, keyboard-navigation

**My Question:** Is there an equivalent keyboard shortcut in Mac OS X to the windows one where you type <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> and it will launch the first application in your taskbar (see the first shortcut mentioned in [this post](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/37176/20-windows-keyboard-shortcuts-you-might-not-know/) on howtogeek.com)?

I just started using a MacBook Pro I got from work and I'd just love to have this feature that I used all the time on Windows. (In fact, if anyone knows of has a good post helping superusers of windows make the transition to mac that would be sweet too).

I would be willing to accept an answer that points to an application which would support this functionality. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download a 99 cent app from the mac app store called "[Snap](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/snap/id418073146?mt=12)" to do this. Hit command-1 and the first app in the dock launches.

Comment: It was free when I just downloaded it